# If order contains virtual product add PDF

Tags: php, pdf, virtual-products

I am adding a PDF to all my sales emails at the moment, but I only want these PDFs to be added if the order contains at least one virtual product.
How can I implent this in the following if statement?

```
    if (Mage::getStoreConfig('sales_email/' . $configPath . '/attachpdf', $storeId)) {

        //Create Pdf and attach to email - play nicely with PdfCustomiser

        $pdf = Mage::getModel('emailattachments/order_pdf_order')->getPdf(array($order));
        Mage::helper('emailattachments')->addAttachment(
            $pdf, $mailTemplate, $this->getOrderAttachmentName($order)
        );
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    $isVirtual = false;
    foreach ($order->getAllItems() as $items) {            
        if ($items->getProductType() == 'virtual') {
            $isVirtual = true; 
            break;
        }
    }

    if (Mage::getStoreConfig('sales_email/' . $configPath . '/attachpdf', $storeId) && $isVirtual) {

        //Create Pdf and attach to email - play nicely with PdfCustomiser

        $pdf = Mage::getModel('emailattachments/order_pdf_order')->getPdf(array($order));
        Mage::helper('emailattachments')->addAttachment(
            $pdf, $mailTemplate, $this->getOrderAttachmentName($order)
        );
    }
```

Comment: Thank you very much @eetzen. It is now adding a PDF if the order only contains virtual products, however I would like to add the PDF also if it contains both virtual and another type of products. Normal products = false, virtual + normal products = true, virtual products = true. Is this possible to add?

Comment: I only use configurable, virtual and simple products if that makes a difference :)

Comment: the code should work as long as there's a virtual product in the order.

Comment: Sadly the PDF is not being added if I purchase both a simple and a virtual product.

Comment: I found out that I simply had to remove the break; and then it works. Thank you very much for your help :)